# For loop creates NA after 2th row

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying use first row and repeat same process for last row.

```
mt0 <- 15
c0 <- 1.2
F <- 1
W <- 0.55
V <- 1.5
yt_value_test <- c(16.28948, 15.07612, 14.68842, 16.13255, 14.21511, 14.10924, 14.18346, 15.46259)
Mt_index <- mt0
Ct_index <- W + c0
Ot <- F*Mt_index
Qt <- V+F^2
Mt <- Mt_index + Ct_index*F*(Qt^-1)*(yt_value_test[1] - Ot)
Ct <- Ct_index - (Ct_index*F*(Qt^-1)*Ct_index)

table2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Mt_index, Ct_index, Ot, Qt, Mt, Ct))
attach(table2)
show(table2)
```

output:

```
> table2
  Mt_index Ct_index Ot  Qt       Mt    Ct
1       15     1.75 15 2.5 15.90264 0.525
```

For loop I'm using above process for data[i], second created like just  like I wanted, but after that loop creates NA

```
for (i in 1:8)
{
Mt_index <- Mt[i]

Ct_index <- W + Ct[i]

Ot <- F*Mt_index[i]

Qt <- V+F^2

Mt <- Mt_index[i] + Ct_index[i]*F*(Qt[i]^-1)*(yt_value_test[i] - Ot[i])

Ct <- Ct_index[i] - (Ct_index[i]*F*(Qt[i]^-1)*Ct_index[i])

    table2 <- rbind(table2, c(Mt_index, Ct_index, Ot, Qt, Mt, Ct))
}
```

output creates NA which I don't know why

```
> table2
  Mt_index Ct_index       Ot  Qt       Mt      Ct
1 15.00000    1.750 15.00000 2.5 15.90264 0.52500
2 15.90264    1.075 15.90264 2.5 16.06898 0.61275
3       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
4       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
5       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
6       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
7       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
8       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
9       NA       NA       NA 2.5       NA      NA
>
```

second row is correct what I tried to do. 3th row should start Mt_index[3] Mt[2] which is 16.06898. Like first row Mt values second row Mt_index values.

Comment: I can't reproduce your code, V doesn't exist.

Comment: uhh, sorry V is 1.5, I'm tracking text book formula. which is why I'm using variable for single value.

Comment: `Mt` has length 1?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying using first table2 first row values and repeat process in for loop.

Comment: You are trying to index on vectors with just one element. Mt[3] is NA.

Comment: hmm, I do understand but before loop MT[2] was NA but after end of loop 2th row created correctly. How do I repeat for rest of the row.

Comment: Actually, the second row is created with Mt[1] not Mt[2], because table2 already existed before the loop started.

Comment: Well how do I proceed :D. End of loop MT[2] is not NA, why loop ignores since i in 1:8?

Answer (score 0):

there are some details of your data that I still don't understand. However, it seems that you need to complete rows 2 to 9 and not 1 to 8. Here's what I did. You may have to make small changes to fix any issues but this is probably a good starting point.

```
for (i in 2:9){
  Mt_index <- table2$Mt[i-1]
  Ct_index <- W + table2$Ct[i-1]
  Ot <- F*table2$Mt_index[i-1]
  Qt <- V+F^2
  Mt <- table2$Mt_index[i-1] + table2$Ct_index[i-1]*F*(table2$Qt[i-1]^-1)*(table2$yt_value_test[i-1] - table2$Ot[i-1])
  Ct <- table2$Ct_index[i-1] - (table2$Ct_index[i-1]*F*(table2$Qt[i-1]^-1)*table2$Ct_index[i-1])
  table2 <- rbind(table2, c(Mt_index, Ct_index, Ot, Qt, Mt, Ct))
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: jose pointed first Mt was mt[1], I should run for 2:9, And tried i-1 just like you did, table 2 shows unexpected values. like 3     0.525000  16.452636  15.902636 2.5     0.612750     0.525000,